# What happens when I pass arguments to a Clojure symbol?

Tags: clojure, symbols

If I do this:

```
('a 'b 'c)
```

I get this:

```
c
```

Why?

Comment: It shouldn't be `(list 'a 'b 'c)`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The link Hauleth posted is a good overview to symbols but the answer to your question is that calling a symbol as a function is equivalent to looking that symbol up in the first argument.

```
('a 'b)
```

is equivalent to

```
(get 'b 'a)
```

The documentation for get shows that you can pass an optional third argument as the default. In your example 'c is treated as the default and returned since 'b is not a map and 'a can't be found.

Comment: you've got the arguments to (get) backwards, but otherwise I'd like to accept your answer

Comment: Sooooo, not only keyword, but symbol too.... and as example we alway put a non quoted symbol witch is not defined, we never thougth about the symbol itself...
That's... hrm, taking habit of syntactic sugar... collection, symbol and keyword are IFn too ;)