# What do Clojure symbols do when used as functions?

Tags: clojure

While trying to solve the 4Clojure problem "[Universal Computation Engine](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/121)" involving reimplementing evaluation, I accidentally ended up calling something like this:

```
(apply '/ '(16 8))
```

rather than the intended:

```
(apply / '(16 8))
```

This had the confusing side effect of returning `8`, which made me think I had messed up my maths.

I later realised my error after some debugging—I was failing to evaluate the `/` symbol before attempting to call it—and so realised that `clojure.lang.Symbol` must implement `clojure.lang.IFn`. But what does that implementation *do*? All I can get it to do is return `nil` with one argument, or the second argument if given.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happens when I pass arguments to a Clojure symbol?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219305/what-happens-when-i-pass-arguments-to-a-clojure-symbol)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Symbols *look themselves up* in a map, much as keywords do.  See [Symbol's implementation](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Symbol.java#L122):

```
…
122 public Object invoke(Object obj) {
123         return RT.get(obj, this);
124 }
125
126 public Object invoke(Object obj, Object notFound) {
127         return RT.get(obj, this, notFound);
128 }
…
```

(`RT` is [`clojure.lang.RT`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java), which does just about everything. "RunTime"?)

In the example given, the lookup is failing (because 16 is not a map), and therefore the `notFound` value (8) is being returned.