# Calling a list of methods on a Java object using Clojure

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

I have a list of values I want to convert to an immutable Java POJO. The Java POJO gets generated using the builder pattern.

The list I have is:

```
[49.0 11.1 150.0]
```

In Java my POJO would get constructed like this:

```
Position.builder().latitude(49.0).longitude(11.1).altitude(150.0).build()
```

I thought to create it in Clojure I would first `zipmap` the values with the methods that need to be used and then I could `reduce-kv` everything to the Java value I need:

```
(defn poslist->map [list]
      (zipmap ['.latitude '.longitude '.altitude]
              list))

(.build (reduce-kv #(%2 %1 %3) 
                   (pkg.Position/builder)
                   (poslist->map list)))
```

My problem now is that I don't get what I expect. The function `poslist->map` returns the expected value:

```
{.latitude 49.0, .longitude 11.1, .altitude 150.0}
```

But the `reduce-kv` just returns the last value I have:

```
150.0
```

Why don't I get back the builder on which I then can apply the `.build` method? I had expected that the `reduce-kv` to have the same result as the following code that returns what I expect:

```
(.build (.altitude (.longitude (.latitude (pkg.Position/builder) 150.0) 11.1) 49.0))
```

And as the `reduce-kv` function returns a double the following call of `.build` failes with

```
No matching field found: build for class java.lang.Double
```

BTW: The reason I am mapping the methods to the list values is, that the actual list of fields I have to set is longer as in the example. I stripped down the example to be more readable while retaining my basic problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Clojure symbols [*act* as functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281631/what-do-clojure-symbols-do-when-used-as-functions), they are not connected with functions with the same name in any way:

```
> ('.add (java.util.ArrayList.) 1)
1
> ('first [1 2 3])
nil
> ('conj [1 2] 3)
3
```

So the issue, basically, is that java methods are not called at all. To fix it wrap your iterop methods with [`memfn`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/memfn):

```
['.latitude '.longitude '.altitude]

->

[(memfn latitude val) (memfn longitude val) (memfn altitude val)]
```

or, as @noisesmith suggested, with clojure functions:

```
->

[#(.latitude %1 %2) #(.longitude %1 %2) #(.altitude %1 %2)]
```

Comment: there's no situation currently where `(memfn foo)` is preferable to `#(.foo %)`

Comment: Thank you both, that works! Just one note: to match exactly my question, the created function takes two parameters (the builder instance and the value to set). Therefore it's either `(memfn latitude val)` or `#(.latitude %1 %2)`.