# Clojure operators in higher-order functions

Tags: clojure

I've put together a higher order function that in certain cases calls a function parameter, but it seems to have different effects depending on the function. I was able to reproduce the same behaviour just with a simple function:

```clj
(defn foo [f a b] (f a b))
```

For "normal" functions it works fine:

```clj
user=> (foo list 2 3)
(2 3)
user=> (foo cons 1 '(2 3))
(1 2 3)
user=> (foo println 2 3)
2 3
nil
```

But for operators, it does not, it just seems to return the last element:

```
user=> (foo '+ 2 3)
3
user=> (foo '* 2 3)
3
user=> (foo '- 2 3)
3
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: Just as a fun fact of why "it just seems to return the last element", see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12281633/3000206) (the second arg given is a default, which it's defaulting to). I don't know why you'd need to do this, but it lets you do something like `('+ {'+ 2})` returns 2.

Comment: @Carcigenicate For the same reason you'd want to do it for keywords, of course. Sometimes you might just have a map keyed by symbol for whatever reason (e.g., the lexical environment when implementing an interpreter), and it's not crazy to want to be able to use symbols as functions to look themselves up.

Comment: @amalloy That's true. I just don't think I've ever had the need to do a lookup like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
user=> (foo '+ 2 3)
3
```

> Why is this the case?

`'` (or `quote`) is creating a *symbol* of `+` when you want the `+` function value itself: https://clojure.org/guides/weird_characters#_quote

```
(quote foo) => foo ;; symbol
'foo => foo ;; symbol
```

So the behavior of always returning the second argument comes from the fact that symbols (like keywords) also act as functions, typically used as a shorthand for `get` on associative structures (like maps), so these are functionally equivalent:

```
('foo 1 2) => 2
(get 1 'foo 2) => 2
```

The `2` happens to be in the position used for *default* values when the key isn't found in the associative structure.

This would be useful if you had a map with symbol keys, just like keywords:

```
('foo {'foo 1}) => 1
({'foo 1} 'foo) => 1
('foo {'bar 1} 2) => 2
```

Comment: Crazy!  I have never heard of this.  I would consider it a "gotcha" instead of a "feature".

Answer (score 1):

In clojure, "operators" like `+` are just normal functions.  Don't use the single-quote and it'll work fine.

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(defn foo [f a b] (f a b))

(dotest
  (spyx (foo list 2 3))
  (spyx (foo println 2 3))
  (spyx (foo + 2 3))
  (spyx (foo * 2 3))
  (spyx (foo - 2 3)) )
```

with results:

```
(foo list 2 3) => (2 3)

2 3                        ; result of (println 2 3)
(foo println 2 3) => nil   ; println always returns `nil`

(foo + 2 3) => 5
(foo * 2 3) => 6
(foo - 2 3) => -1
```

The helper function `spyx` just prints an expression, then its value.